# Django .save() method is not appearing in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I am relatively new to python and currently exploring django.
I am facing this problem in Visual Studio Code where the save() method is not reflected in my main app. The method reflects in other apps and I am not sure how to go about solving this. The codes are situated in the views.py of the respective applications.

[For this image, form.save() does not return any method which results in not saving any information. This is situated in my main app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d8xW.png)

[For this image, form.save() returns a method that allows the saving of information. This is situated in my register app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwmL1.png)

Comment: please copy your code and prevent sending images.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the code itself but your IDE, sometimes the Python engine that suggest might not work accordingly.

However it is a common issue, you can still use the method "save", it is just not autosuggested

[Troubleshooting Intellisense VSCODE](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense)